# Using ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly with Azure SQL Database Failover group and Primary Connection String

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have started using ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly; for Premium Databases which works great.

However if I use the Fail-over group connection then the connection is always READ_WRITE. Can you not use ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly with the main FOG connection string:
Server=tcp:xxxx-fog.database.windows.net,1433;Persist Security Info=False;Connection Timeout=300;TrustServerCertificate=True;Database=xxx;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;

I can use the geo-secondary fine for this - but we already have a lot of load on the geo-secondary, so I wanted to use some of the primary replicas for reading too.

Comment: please make sure you have enabled the readscale setting on the db:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/set-azurermsqldatabase?view=azurermps-6.8.1

Comment: Yup it is enabled - if I use the server connection string, not the Fail-over-group connection string it works perfectly.  This isn't ideal though, because it means queries will fail if failed-over.

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationIntent allows routing to a local HA replica of Premium or Business Critical databases. When using failover groups, to load balance read-only traffic you should use Server=tcp:.secondary.database.windows.net. This will work for any database in the FOG (premium or not) and will ensure that the queries do not fail on failover. We recommend also using ApplicationIntent as well. In case you upgrade the database to Premium or Business Critical, this will allow the read-only clients to take advantage of the local HA replica without changing the connection string.

Comment: Thanks for that info - however my understanding is that tcp:.secondary.database.windows.net will always use the secondary (geo-located) database.  We already use this for all our ETL work, but as I mentioned above we want to make useof the primary databases readonly replicas, which this wouldn't do right?

Comment: If your primary is Premium or Business critical, you should use ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly; Server=tcp:fog_name.database.windows.net. After failover it will start routing the sessions to the local HA replica of the new primary database.

Comment: As mentioned above we tried that - but the connection is always READ_WRITE, which leads me to believe its ignoring ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;.  If we use the direct connection string, not the FOG connection string, then it returned READ_ONLY so works

Answer (score 0):

Just to update - Azure have confirmed this is a bug and they are fixing it in the next few weeks.  Where if we turn on Read Scale-Out feature on a database after we add it to a failover group, the connections through failover group endpoint are not honoring read scale out redirections. 
Current workaround before the issue being fixed, is to turn on read scale feature on your databases before adding them to a failover group.

Comment: Does this work for you now, assuming it's been fixed? It's not working for us at the moment.

Comment: yup working fine for us  - make sure you aren't using PRS databases as it doesn't support that.